# How to calculate price after click active and inactive button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate price when i click order button if i re-click order button to cancel order then price will decrees and if i click more then price will increase then show total price. i have done active inactive but fail to calculate price increment/decrement, how can i do that..please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price = 0;
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var priceValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      var price = price + $(this).val();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var price = price - $(this).val();
    }
    alert(price)
   $('#priceDisplay').val(price);
  })
})
```

```css
.btn {
  color: white;
  background: orange;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Rice</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn" value="30">Order</button></td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Egg</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn " value="25">Order</button></td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dal</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn " value="20">Order</button>
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="priceDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: So when you click "Order" on "Egg" for example, what should happen EXACTLY? `price will decrease` by how much? Should it be shown next to "Egg"? `price will increase then show total price` by how much still? And show total price where? Of what?

Comment: Oh and you're redefining your variable price every time, which is a very bad idea

Comment: i will take Egg price and calculate this price if another select and finally total price will show , if cancel any order then price will decrese

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy this is my example code , all menu list will show from database and price will different.

Comment: it is as like e-commerce ad-to cart system

Comment: @Md.AzharulIslam check my snippet :)

Comment: i am developing restaurant type food order , customer can order multiple food item

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price = 0;
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var priceValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      
       price = price - parseInt($(this).val());
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
       price = price + parseInt($(this).val());
    }
   $('#priceDisplay').text(price);
  })
})
```

```css
.btn {
  color: white;
  background: orange;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Rice</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn" value="30">Order</button></td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Egg</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn " value="25">Order</button></td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dal</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="button" class="btn " value="20">Order</button>
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="priceDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you're not parsing values to `int`. 
after small update can you try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price = 0;
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var priceValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      price += parseInt($(this).val());
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      price -= $(this).val();
    }
    alert(price)
   $('#priceDisplay').text(price);
  })
})
```